# Delete old backup files in pentaho etl tool

Tags: database, file, etl

I want to know how to delete files based the creation date using a kettle job. I have a log folder which contains log files for last four years. But I want to keep only last week log files. The job should be deleting all the log files which are more than one month old. There is a delete file option in pentaho job. But how do we get file creation date and delete the files accordingly.

Step by step process I used to create kettle:

1. Get file name
2. Get system info
3. Add constants
4. Database lookup: here I am using postgresql it lookup the field the entity_name and attribute_name from database and date is inserted in database by using this database lookup.
5. Select values:
6. Calculator
7. Filter rows
8. Set files in result
9. Process files with option delete.

I want to ask that i am having filename for eg:abcd_2018_06_05.backup.
I have to use hard core regular expression to define above filename.Could anybody help me to define it so that it can take right(file_name, len(file_name)-7).

I know how it can be done in a SQL query, but in pentaho I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

The get filenames step also returns the last modified timestamp. Can’t you use that instead?

Something like this:

Get filenames -> get system info (to get current date) -> calculator (subtract 7 days from current date -> filter rows (let only files older than 7 days through) -> process files: delete (delete old files.

Alternatively, using the regex step you can parse the filename and then filter rows.

Comment: before process files step i have to use regex step to parse the filename but what will be the expression to parse the filename for eg:filename is abcd_2018_06_01.backup

Comment: i have to extract date from above filename by using pattern recognition how i can do that

Comment: You can either use strings cut to take a portion of fixed length or regex evaluation to parse more complicated patterns.

Comment: hei how i can write regex to parse value for eg:filename-abcd_2018_06_01. I tried "_\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}" this but i am getting error. boolean can't converted to date

Comment: your regex is .*_([0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{4})\.backup

Comment: notice the capture group. You need to then define the capture group in the bottom part of the regex step. The result field is just a boolean stating whether or not the row matches the regex.

Comment: I already defined capture group fields "New field:date and Type:Date".Then also i am getting same error .Can anybody help me to write regular expression to extract date from above file name?

Comment: Thanks! Now i amnot getting error but Date field is null i want 2018_06_01 as output

Comment: hei can anybody help me i am getting Date field is returing value <null> not extracting data from filename.

Comment: test your regex. you may have a typo. Or I may have a typo above. But you're clearly missing the point of how stackoverflow works.

Comment: i am having one question as i am deleting files which are older than 7 days,and i want to delete file which are older than 12 months but keep files created at the 1st day of every month for eg: dated 2019-01-01,2019-02-01,2019-03-01 like wise for every month i have to write logic in filter rows or i have to take one more step after filter rows.

Comment: Definitely not a suitable discussion for the comments thread. You should ask that on a separate question

Comment: could you please help me to write logic. I asked above question as separate question.I am stuck here.

Comment: what you're asking goes well beyond what stackoverflow is meant to do.